# Calculate regular polygon vertices

Tags: geometry

[image]
As shown above, I want to calculate the vertices of a regular polygon. If there is a vertex on the $x$-axis, I can calculate it, but my side is on the $x$-axis, and I cannot calculate it. Please help me, thank you!
​

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Rotations are well understood: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes_in_two_dimensions

Comment: Do you have a numbering scheme in order to keep track of which vertex you are calculating for which polygon and size?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the number of points in these figures or their coordinates?

Comment: So you are asking for $(x,y)$ for [something like this?](https://i.imgur.com/eTIqg31.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "$x$-axis" as there doesn't appear to be a graph on the diagram, however, it seems as though you're asking for the amount of vertices in the $i$th iteration, depicted in the diagram, for a regular polygon with $n$ sides.

There are several ways of solving this (such as a geometrical breakdown into algebraic expressions), however the easiest is to notice the numerical pattern from the given shapes already. Notice that for a square, with $4$ sides, the number of vertices follows this sequence through iterations: $1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, ...$, the sequence of difference is then $3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ...$. Then the second difference sequence is $2, 2, 2, 2, ...$. The difference table looks as so:
[Difference table for square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReMgd.png), where $i$ is the iteration and $f(i)$ is some function that outputs the number of vertices in the sequence of squares.

Next, for a pentagon, with $5$ sides:
[Difference table for pentagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrH0h.png), where $g(i)$ is some function that outputs the number of vertices in the sequence of pentagons.

From here, it's clear that for an $n$ sided polygon the final difference, $\Delta^2$, will be $n-2$. Therefore, we can build a difference table using $n-2$ (notice that for any $n$ sided polygon, $i=0$ will always be $1$ and $i=1$ will always be $n$): [Difference table for n sided polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcC5V.png), where $F_n(i)$ is some function that outputs the vertices of an $n$ sided polygon.

Finally, using the difference table of the standard quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c$,

> For futher reading: https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/quadratic-sequences.html

we know

$$a = \frac{\Delta^2}{2} = \frac{n-2}{2}$$

$$b = \Delta_{0} - a = n-1 - \frac{n-2}{2} = \frac{2n-2-(n-2)}{2} = \frac{n}{2}$$

$$c = F_n(0) = 1$$
Therefore, for an $n$ sided polygon the number of vertices in the specified sequence at the $i$th iteration is $F_n(i) = \frac{n-2}{2}i^2 + \frac{n}{2}i + 1$.